# ASP.NET hyperlink with font-awesome icon

Tags: css, asp.net

How to add font awesome icon in a hyperlink in asp.net with this format on html bootsrap :

`<a href="#"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i>CONTACT US</a>`

Thanks for your response in advance

Comment: It would help to know what you're seeing. My guess: some garbage character next to "CONTACT US". I'm thinking the correct form for your `class` attribute is `class="fa fa-phone"` dropping the `s` from `fas`. Also make sure that your font-awesome style sheet is available to the page.

Comment: I used the same class  attribute on my html page and it works perfectly fine, what I want to do right now is to have the same looks  on my asp page and on my html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can do like this if you want to use anchor tag like button using bootstrap with Icon.

```
<a class="btn"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Contact Us</a>
```

References : [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_icon_buttons.asp)

If you want to use it in <asp:HyperLink> then you can use like this

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="test" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Contact Us"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> Contact Us</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, how can I put font awesome on my hyperlink in asp.net

`<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink3" NavigateUrl="#" Text="SIGN IN" runat="server" />'

Answer (score 1):

close your `</i>` after Contact US
your correct code is:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">
<i class="fas fa-phone">CONTACT US</i>
</a>
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, how can I put font awesome on my hyperlink in asp.net

`<asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink3" NavigateUrl="#" Text="SIGN IN" runat="server" />'

Comment: <asp:HyperLink id="hyperlink3" NavigateUrl="#" Text="SIGN IN" runat="server" ><i class="fas fa-phone">CONTACT US</i></asp:HyperLink>